# Input field styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want when user focuses on input field the label and border of input field should be red and when user leaves both label and border of input field should turn to green. Also when user focuses and does not enter any value both label and border again in red color.

```css
.field {
  position: relative;
}

.inName {
  position: absolute;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.laName {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(95, 99, 105);
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  transition: .3s;
}

.inName:focus+.laName {
  top: -12px;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: crimson;
}

.inName:not(:placeholder-shown).inName:not(:focus)+.laName {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: crimson;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .3s;
}

.inName:focus {
  border: 1px solid crimson;
}
```

```html
<div class="field name">
  <input type="text" class="inName" placeholder=" ">
  <label for="" class="laName">Name</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I think you could add color: green in your `.inName:not(:placeholder-shown).inName:not(:focus)+.laName` class and also add another class `.inName:not(:placeholder-shown).inName:not(:focus)` that will have border set to green. Here's your code with the changes(I commented where the changes are):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>

<head>
<style>
    .field {
    position: relative;
    }

    .inName {
    position: absolute;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    }

    .laName { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgb(95, 99, 105);
    z-index: 1;
    background: #fff;
    transition: .3s;
    }

     .inName:focus+.laName {
     top: -12px;
     font-size: 15px;
     padding: 0 5px;
     color: crimson;
     }

    .inName:not(:placeholder-shown).inName:not(:focus)+.laName {
position: absolute;
top: -12px;
pointer-events: none;
padding: 0 5px;
font-size: 15px;
background-color: #ffffff;
/*CHANGE HERE COLOR TO GREEN*/
color: green;
z-index: 1;
transition: .3s;
}

.inName:focus {
border: 1px solid crimson;
} 
/*ADD THIS*/
.inName:not(:placeholder-shown).inName:not(:focus){
    border: 1px solid green;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="field name">
<input type="text" class="inName" placeholder=" ">
<label for="" class="laName">Name</label>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

That can be done using JS event listeners - `focus` and `change`

**Here is a fast scratch of what you can do:**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener("focus", focus);
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener("change", focus);

function focus() {
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  if (input.value.length === 0) {
    input.style.borderColor = "red"; // for input
    input.nextElementSibling.style.color = "red"; // for label
  } else {
    input.style.borderColor = "green"; // for input
    input.nextElementSibling.style.color = "green"; // for label
  }
}
```

Also set input border color to green in CSS as default for the first load.